# Adding spacing in mathtools' `set` command

Tags: spacing, scaling, mathtools, mathematics

In the [mathtools documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathtools/mathtools.pdf#page=27), page 27, a command `\Set*` (along with `\Set`) is defined to stretch according to the large input inside:

```
\providecommand\given{}

\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{
    \nonscript\:#1\vert
    \allowbreak
    \nonscript\:
    \mathopen{}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{
    \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}
    #1
}
```

For instance, using the above command, the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
    \Set{(2,\pm 1)} \cup \Set*{\left (\frac{2t^2 - 2t + 2}{t^2 + 1},\, \frac{1-t^2}{t+1}\right ) \given t \neq -1 }
\]
\end{document}
```

produces
[image: Result1]

Now, I quite like the automatic scaling options. However, in my old own `\Set` command, I always added some space around the argument:

```
\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\{\, #1 \,\}}
```

This produced something like
[image: Result2]
In this case, the extra spacing is particularly easy to see in the set on the left of the `\cup`.

Does anyone know how this spacing behaviour might be added to mathtools' approach to defining a set-command? Or even to create something entirely different, but which achieves both the scaling and the spacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the thin spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\providecommand\given{}

\newcommand\SetSymbol[1][]{%
  \nonscript\:#1\vert
  \allowbreak
  \nonscript\:%
  \mathopen{}%
}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\Set[1]\{\}{%
  \renewcommand\given{\SetSymbol[\delimsize]}%
  \,#1\,% <--- thin spaces around the part in braces
}

\begin{document}

\[
\Set{(2,\pm 1)} \cup
\Set*{\left (\frac{2t^2 - 2t + 2}{t^2 + 1},\, \frac{1-t^2}{t+1}\right )
      \given t \neq -1 }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]